# How to stop iPhoto and iTunes from opening automatically when plugging in an iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, iphoto

I'm still pretty much a noob in OS X (Snow Leopard, if that makes any difference).

How to stop iPhoto and iTunes from opening automatically when plugging in an iPhone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer to how to stop iPhoto from opening here: http://michaelkrol.com/2007/09/13/tell-your-iphone-to-stop-opening-iphoto/

> Open Image Capture and go to the Preferences menu (under the Image Capture menu item). Under the General tab, change the option for “When a camera is connected…” to “No Application” instead of “iPhoto”.
>
> This means you’ll have to manually start iPhoto when you connect your digital camera, but you won’t have to CLOSE iPhoto every time you plug in your iPhone (which, for me, is a heck of a lot more often than plugging in a camera!)

Comment: In Snow Leopard and Image Capture version 6 the process is slightly different: select the iPhone in Image Captre and then choose "No application" from the "When I connect this iPhone" dropdown in the lower left.

Comment: @blahdiblah Your comment applies to Lion as well.

Answer (score 3):

iTunes has an option to automatically start iTunes when the iPod is connected ...  I assume the same option is there when you connect an iPhone on the Mac. Simply uncheck the checkbox.

Connect the iPhone, click on it in the left hand panel on iTunes, and look for the option over on the right. (Main tab).

Comment: Where is that option? Does it still exist?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't remember, and I don't use iTunes any more.

Answer (score 2):

#### For iTunes select your device and uncheck `Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected`

[image]

---

#### For Image Capture, select the up symbol and then select `No Application`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For iPhoto, do like alxp said.

For iTunes, you can also remove the iTunesHelper in your launching elements.
This will not load iTunes when any iPhone is plug.

Answer (score 0):

I find this,
http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/09/29/how-to-stop-iphoto-from-opening-when-you-plug-in-an-ipod-touch-or-any-device-with-a-camera/ 
sry for posting link I'm busy now and can't post it here with photo. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is also an excellent control panel add-on called Cameras for Mac OS X which allows you to choose what it will do if you connect, say an iPhone, your DSLR or any other camera like the device. Best of all, it free. You can specify in the control panel what action the mac will take when a certian device hooks up to machine. [You can download it here](http://www.flexibits.com/) This utily won't disable iPhoto completely from launching on device connect, but only for the devices you want. It iritated me 2 everytime I connected my iPhone, iPhoto would automatically launch, and this works great. It's been a bit flaky under Snow Leopard though, so update wouldn't hurt either @flexibits